# Submit form after selecting all file type input fields

Tags: jquery

I have image up loader page containing 4 file type input fields, now i want that, user should submit form after selecting all 4 images instead of less than 4 image file. i.e. In my page user can submit after 1 file select but I just submit the form after all files selection. please help me.

```js
$('#upimg').submit(function() {

  $(".imgp").each(function() {
    var imgnm = $(this).val();
    if (imgnm === '') {
      $("#dialog").html("<p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;'></span>Please select Image to upload.</p>");
      $("#dialog").dialog("open");
      return prevantDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong style="color: red; font-size: larger;">*</strong>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="imgfile[]" id="imgfile" class="imgp">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder='image name' type="text" size="20" class="inm ui-corner-all ui-widget input" id="imgname" name="imgname[]">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong style="color: red; font-size: larger;">*</strong>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="imgfile[]" id="imgfile" class="imgp">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder='image name' type="text" size="20" class="inm ui-corner-all ui-widget input" id="imgname" name="imgname[]">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong style="color: red; font-size: larger;">*</strong>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="imgfile[]" id="imgfile" class="imgp">
      </td>
      <td>
        <inputp placeholder='image name' type="text" size="20" class="inm ui-corner-all ui-widget input" id="imgname" name="imgname[]">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong style="color: red; font-size: larger;">*</strong>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="imgfile[]" id="imgfile" class="imgp">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input placeholder='image name' type="text" size="20" class="inm ui-corner-all ui-widget input" id="imgname" name="imgname[]">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tr align="center">
    <td colspan="4">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text">&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

I have used four input file because user can separately change image file name.
How can i set that user must submit form after all 4 image selection.

Comment: could you create a fiddle of your code ?

Comment: I am totally new here i can't understand @DinoMyte

Comment: go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and paste your code there.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/satyajitbho/yceyc919/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yceyc919/1/

js :

```
$('.imgp').each(function() {            
    $(this).change(function(){          
        if ($(this).val()){
                $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
            }
            else {
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',true);
            }
        var file_size = $(this)[0].files[0].size;
        var imgkbytes = Math.round(parseInt(file_size)/1024);
        if(file_size>256001) {
            $("#uplod").html("<p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;'></span>File size is too large "+imgkbytes+"kb.</p>");
            $("#uplod").dialog("open");
            $(this).val(null);
        }
    });
});

   $('#button').on("click",function(e) {
       var error = false;
   if($("#gallery").val() == 0)
   {
      $("#dialog").html("<p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert'     style='float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;'></span>Please select the Gallery Name.</p>");
       error = true;                
   }       

     $(".imgp").each(function(){
        var imgnm = $(this).val();  
        if(imgnm == ''){
            $("#dialog").append("<p><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;'></span>Please select Image to upload.</p>");           
            error = true;
        }
        });
  if(error)
  {
      $("#dialog").dialog();
      e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Awesome sir, it works, thank you thank you thank you.. @DinoMyte